# Javascript Values getting cancelled out in AJAX.

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

this is a very strange situation.  I am looping through some divs to gather information to send to my back-end PHP, but one of the values never makes it to the back end.

Here is my front-end code:

```
    $(".allDivs").each(function(){

        var symbol; 
        var currentId = $(this).attr("id"); 
        var currentId = currentId.replace("div", "");

        var originalSymbol = $.trim($("#symbol" + currentId).val()); 
        var offerPrice = $.trim($("#offerPrice" + currentId).val());

        if (originalSymbol.length == 5)
        {
            symbol = originalSymbol.slice(0,-1); 
        }
        else
        {
            symbol = originalSymbol;            
        }

        symbolArray.push({
            "symbol": symbol, 
            "originalSymbol" : originalSymbol,
            "offerPrice" : offerPrice, 
            "checkNews" : "TEST", 
            "idNumber": currentId, 
        });

});
```

If I debug the object right before calling AJAX, here is what it looks like:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(symbolArray));
```

Produces:

```
    [{"symbol":"MSFT","originalSymbol":"MSFT","offerPrice":"","checkNews":"TEST","idNumber":"1"}]
```

So you can see that the value for checkNews is "TEST"

Here is what the AJAX looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "newsproxy.php",
        data: {symbols: JSON.stringify(symbolArray)}, 
    async: true,            
        dataType: 'json',
        success:  function (data) {
// etc...
```

If I try to print out some of the information at the back end, here is what it looks like:

```
  if(isset($_GET['symbols']))
  {
    $symbols=$_GET['symbols']; 
  }

  foreach ($symbols as $symbol)
  {
     $symbol = $symbol->symbol;
     $checkNews = $symbol->checkNews; 

     echo "symbol is *" . $symbol . "*" . " and checkNews is *" . $checkNews . "*";
  }
```

This produces the following:

```
  symbol is *MSFT* and checkNews is **
```

Why would my symbol variable make it to the back-end, but the checkNews variable gets cancelled out?

Comment: Note you are sending `symbols` value as JSON, which is a string value, to get your object you need to decode first. So you arent showing that or you are showing the wrong output

Comment: You are overwriting `$symbol` (your object) with your `symbol` string value, use a different variable name

Comment: That was it Patrick thank you, much appreciated.